# How to use DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream) for data of type object?

Tags: c#, json

I have a variable of type `Object`, which holds JSON data. I need to deserialize this JSON data to my Data Contract class, but `DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream)` accepts `Stream` type as an argument, and I need to pass argument of type `Object`. 
How can I deserialize this data?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by, *I have a variable of type `Object`, which holds JSON data.*?  Is it actually a string, or something else?  A true [`object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) cannot actually hold any data so it's likely your variable is actually a subtype of object.

Comment: It is a Dictionary. But I don't know it's a Dictionary in advance. I get it as an object. Only when I call ReadObject I know it's a Dictionary type.

Comment: We're having some difficulty understanding your precise situation.  Can you provide a [minimal but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how you obtain your JSON data and what you want to do with it next?

Comment: ok. I have a JSON stream, which includes an array. Each of this array element exists of 3 fields: name, type and value. name and type fields are strings. value is either string, int, dictionary of strings or other complex struct. Since I don't know in advance the type of value field, I declared its type in the data contract as object. Now,

Comment: Now, deserialization works fine, and for the array elements which its value type is string or int, the value field is displayed correctly. But for the complex types, I should perform deserialization again, and here's the problem. Once this field is of type object, I can't convert it to string/stream/something I can call any deserialization method with.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(paramJson);
```

The function is available in Newtonsoft.Json which is available through nuget.

Comment: Tried this. Not helping. Because paramJson should be a string, and my problem is that my paramJson is of object type. I can't figure out how to perform unboxing to it. I tried paramJson.ToString() but I get an exception.